# Django Two Model Fields, same DB Column

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

We are trying to work with legacy DB Tables that were generated outside of Django and are not structured in an ideal way.  We also can not modify the existing tables.

The DB uses the same user ID (pk) across all the tables, wether or not there is a record for that user ID.  It also uses that ID as a PK on the other tables, rather than rely on them to auto increment their own IDs.

So imagine something like this below:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='UserID')

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class UserTypeA(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # Same Value as User

class UserTypeB(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # Same Value as User
```

What we thought of creating a relationship between Items and UserTypeA (as well as UserTypeB) is to create another field entry that uses the same column as the user_id.

```
class Items(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='UserID')
    user_type_a = models.ForeignKey('UserTypeA', db_column='UserID')
    user_type_b = models.ForeignKey('UserTypeB', db_column='UserID')
```

This unfortunately returns a "db_column is already used" type error.

Any thoughts on how to better approach the way what we're trying to do?

A detail to note is that we're only ever reading from this databases (no updates to), so a read-only solution is fine.

Thanks,
-RB

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you have the same field (UserID) in your Items table that point to two distincts tables (UserTypeA, UserTypeB)? If so, how you can tell which table a specific entry in Items table points to?

Comment: They all use the same ID number in the three User databases and are only auto incremented on the "User" model.  For example, ID=300 in User would also be ID=300 in UserTypeA and ID=300 in UserTypeB (assuming there is even a record in either of those tables).  A lot of this would be easier had they designed the data with unique PKs in each of the "UserType" tables.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure it's actually an error—is it system check [`models.E007`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/checks/#models) that you're talking about? You could try [silencing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS) it and seeing if it works...

Comment: is there a compelling reason to have UserTypeA and UserTypeB? can't you use one table and have a flag in it?

Comment: If the values are always the same, why do you make several fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem with this (this code should be put before the definition of your Model):

```
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared

def remove_field(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.__name__ == "MyModel":
        sender._meta.local_fields.remove(sender.myFKField.field)

class_prepared.connect(remove_field)
```

(*Tested in Django 1.5.11*)

Django uses local_fields to make the CREATE TABLE query.

So, I've just attached the signal [class_prepared](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#class-prepared) and check if sender equals the class I was expecting. If so, I've removed the field from that list.

After doing that, the CREATE TABLE query didn't include the field with same db_column and the error did not ocurr.

However the Model still working properly (with manager methods properly populating the removed field from local_fields), I can't tell the real impact of that.